# Partially stacking Tensors

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, tensor

I have some output from a convolutional layer in PyTorch of the shape `[b,c,h]` where `b` is my batches, `c` is my channels, and `h` is the features. I want to stack these to feed into a fully-connected layer without changing the batches, so that they are in the shape `[b, c*h]`. How can I do this?

Comment: Do you mean `[b,c*h]` desired dimension? Why does `b ` change to `x`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like a simple reshape or view should work:

```
input.shape # [b,c,h]

reshaped = input.view(input.shape[0],-1) # [b,c*h]
```